# Worst Case Complexity of this Code in C

Tags: c, complexity-theory

This function takes a character array representing pebbles and
     rearranges the array into RED, WHITE and BLUE characters.
    The number of swaps made while rearranging is also returned.
     The function returns 1 if the input is legal and it is rearranged
     successfully.  It returns 0 if an illegal character is found in the
     input.

```
boolean processInput(char *pebbles, int *noOfSwaps){

    int low;
    int mid;
    int high;

    *noOfSwaps = 0;

    low = 0;

    while (low < strlen(pebbles) && color(*(pebbles + low)) == RED)
            low++;

    high = strlen(pebbles) - 1;

    while (high >= 0 && color(*(pebbles + high)) == BLUE)
            high--;

    mid = low;

    while (mid <= high){

            if (color(*(pebbles + mid)) == RED){

                    if (mid == low){

                            low++;
                            mid++;
                    }

                    else{

                            swap((pebbles + mid), (pebbles + low));

                            (*noOfSwaps)++;
                            low++;
                            mid++;
                    }
            }

            else if (color(*(pebbles + mid)) == WHITE)
                    mid++;

            else if (color(*(pebbles + mid)) == BLUE){
                    if (color(*(pebbles + high)) == BLUE)
                            high--;

                    else{
                            swap((pebbles + mid), (pebbles + high));
                            (*noOfSwaps)++;
                            high--;
                    }
            }      
            else
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

^^^ There's my code above. Just one function. Need to know the worst-case complexity of that function and a reason. Thanks!

Comment: You should post the code here on Stack Overflow if you expect people to answer. Just paste,select, and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Please include the pertinent text of the function here. Also you should provide some of your own estimations about the asymptotic complexity of the function.

Comment: my prediction is O(n)

Comment: On cursory examination it appears to be O(n) where n = strlen(pebbles).

Comment: Worst case scenario is when they are all white. It will go through the whole string to calculate low, then through the whole string to calculate high, then through the whole string incrementing mid each time. O(3n) is O(n) in Computer Science.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dutch National Flag swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258047/dutch-national-flag-swap) - this is the **fourth** identical copy-pasted assignment question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258047/dutch-national-flag-swap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324382/dutch-national-flag and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317965/worst-case-complexity-of-code-in-c

Answer (score 1):

This line would cause a minimum of `O(n) + O(color())` when all of the pebbles are red. If color is `O(1)` (which it probably is), then it's just `O(n)`:

```
while (low < strlen(pebbles) && color(pebbles[low]) == RED)
    low++;
```

The rest of the code appears to only inspect the color of each element once, so that would be `O(n) + O(color())` as well.

So I'm going with `O(n)`.

**Edit:** Scratch that, he calls `strlen` in that while loop. I'm going to upgrade this to `O(n^2)`. Where `n` is the length of `pebbles`. It would be simple to cause this to go back to `O(n)`. Call `strlen()` once, and cache the value.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate this answer. Are you 100% sure that this current code has a worst-case complexity of O(n^2)...I definitely had the same idea as kainaw, with it being O(n). Please get back to me.

Comment: If the array is all red, then the two lines I've copied into my answer will take `O(n^2)`. The rest of the code looks to be `O(n)`. `strlen()` is an `O(n)` operation, and you do it `n` times when everything is red.